# Downloading a Spring MVC generated file not working in IE

Tags: java, spring, internet-explorer, spring-mvc

I have the folowing code for generating a RTF letter in a Spring MVC web app which works ok in Firefox but not in IE 9.

```
public ResponseEntity<String> downloadLetter() {
    String letter = generateLetter();
    final HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.setContentType(new MediaType("text", "rtf"));
    responseHeaders.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"letter.rtf\"");
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(letter, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

IE tries to download a file named as the last part of the url (`letter?param=23`) instead of letter.rtf and then fails completely saying it couldn't be downloaded. Any ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: maybe the quotes in filename="letter.rtf" are throwing it off

Comment: I ended up just using the HttpServletResponse instead - will revisit this later today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE does not support the http status code 201 Created.  Instead, use the standard response for a successful http request, 200 OK.

```
return new ResponseEntity<String>(letter, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
```